# When REPLY_CHANNEL header is used

Tags: spring-integration

[MessageHeaders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/MessageHeaders.html) can contain `replyChannel` key with `Object` type value. I know that in my custom endpoints I can use this header how I want but I think that `replyChannel` header has some default meaning. Please explain to me when `replyChannel` header is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally should not need to manipulate the `replyChannel` header for most applications. It is required by the framework to route replies to request-reply based flows that start with the various types of inbound gateway. Advanced flows might set the reply channel to a channel or channel name but if they are request/reply, originating at a gateway (or `MessagingTemplate`), the original header must eventually be restored.

It is set up by the `MessagingTemplate` whenever a `*sendAndReceive()` message is used, either programmatically, or within a gateway.

Currently, it is not serializable (you can't persist messages mid-flow) because it's a "live" java object instance that the sending thread will expect to find the reply. This is still the case even if you route replies to the gateway by sending them to the `reply-channel` on the gateway; the reply channel on the gateway is bridged to the header channel.

The upcoming 3.0 release has a [new feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new.html#3.0-hcr) which allows registering the header channels and replacing them with strings so they can be serialized, and the framework will restore them from the registry as needed.